# How do you force all insecure assets (CSS and JS) to their https version on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, https, twig

I'm using Laravel and Twig as template language and "https" all around the site. I'm having trouble getting all our non-https assets to transfer over to their https URL's in production.

Both of these...

```
{{ html_style('/css/global.css') }}
{{ html_script('/js/global.js') }}
```

...render this in production:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://website.com/css/global.css">
<script src="http://website.com/js/global.js"></script>
```

...when I want them to render:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://website.com/css/global.css">
<script src="https://website.com/js/global.js"></script>
```

How can I still use relative paths in Laravel and force https on production?

Lastly, I get that this forces https:

```
{{ html_style('css/modals.css',[], true) }}
```

...but then it breaks my local machine because it's looking for https locally.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2):

if you have setup the environments, then use this....

```
{{ html_style('css/modals.css',[], !App::isLocal()) }}
```

though a more elegant solution is [**self signed certificate locally**](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html).